# Gradle configurations.all ambiguous

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I use android studio and gradle to build my project.
Since I've released gradle plugin 12, I have a warning in my build.gradle.
Gradle does not want to force checking dependencies update any more.

This is my build.gradle warning lines :

```
configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

The message is "Method call is ambiguous"

Comment: Sounds like an IDE editor inaccuracy that doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a bug in the IntelliJ (Android Studio) Gradle plugin that I just reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141744.
The warning is wrong and everything should work fine as expected.