# Combining multiple library to use a single exclude list

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my gradle.build, I have various library that perform the same exclusion as below

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5')  {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Obviously, everyone is using the same exclude

```
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Is there a way, that I need only to write the exclude once, and apply to all libraries (at least those that I am interested to perform exclusion)?

Comment: For others looking for a way to force one version only without adding the exclude to other libraries, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347326/4625829)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config to excude for all instance in project:

```
configurations.all { exclude ... }
```

Comment: Where should I put this config? I tried in build.gradle, but it complaints `Method call is ambiguous`

Comment: in android{}, please

Comment: It works, but it is complaining, `Method call is ambiguous`. Is this something of concern?

Comment: Found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177361/gradle-configurations-all-ambiguous. Upvote the answer. Waiting to see if there's other answer before ticking this.